# update random particles in matplotlib using slider

Tags: matplotlib, random, slider

I try to make a plot of random particles, where the number of particles is decreased using a slider.
So far I got the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Teilchen')

x = np.random.randn(50)
y = np.random.randn(50)

plt.plot(x,y, 'o')

axrs = plt.axes([0.125, 0.1, 0.778, 0.03], facecolor='lightblue')
srs = Slider(axrs, 'Zeit', 0, 50, valinit=0, valfmt='%0.0f')

def update1(x): 
    p = round(srs.val,0)
    n = int(50-p)
    x = np.random.randn(n)
    y = np.random.randn(n)
    plt.cla()
    ax.plot(x,y, 'o')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

srs.on_changed(update1)

plt.show()
```

The problem is that instead of redrawing the decreased number of particles, particles get added to the existing plot.
The position of the remaining particles should preferably stay the same over the whole time.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand this correctly. You say that you want the position of the remaining particles to be the same, yet you calculate new random positions on every update. Could you clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ax.clear()` instead of `plt.cla()`.

Explanation: `plt.cla()` clears the current axes. However at the time the slider is updating, the Slider is the current axes and thus the Slider is cleared instead of the axes you want to draw to. To clear a specific axes `ax` you can use `ax.clear()`.

Note that you may also just update the particles instead of redrawing them.

```
x = np.random.randn(50)
y = np.random.randn(50)

particles, = ax.plot(x,y, 'o')

axrs = plt.axes([0.125, 0.1, 0.778, 0.03], facecolor='lightblue')
srs = Slider(axrs, 'Zeit', 0, 50, valinit=50, valfmt='%0.0f')

def update1(val): 
    p = round(val,0)
    n = int(50-p)
    x = np.random.randn(n)
    y = np.random.randn(n)
    particles.set_data(x,y)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

srs.on_changed(update1)

plt.show()
```

To keep the particles position, the idea would of course be not to draw new random numbers but use the random numbers drawn at the beginning.

```
x = np.random.randn(50)
y = np.random.randn(50)

particles, = ax.plot(x,y, 'o')

axrs = plt.axes([0.125, 0.1, 0.778, 0.03], facecolor='lightblue')
srs = Slider(axrs, 'Zeit', 0, 50, valinit=50, valfmt='%0.0f')

def update1(val): 
    p = round(val,0)
    n = int(50-p)
    particles.set_data(x[:n],y[:n])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

srs.on_changed(update1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: But what about the part where he wants the 'remaining particles to stay the same over the whole time'? It would mean not to draw new random numbers and instead somehow limit the existing range, or something like that...

Comment: @Thomas I wasn't sure why the questioner would draw new random numbers if he wants to keep the positions. So in order not to change the positions, no new random numbers should be drawn at all.

Comment: Thank you very much. The second solution is just what I was looking for.